# How to get the file I just unzipped. PHP

Tags: php, unzip

Im unzipping a file, that I dont know the name of its contents.  I need to immediately open and process this file.  How can I grab it? without knowing its name?

Heres my code...

```
if($extension == 'ZIP' || $extension == 'zip'){
     $zip = new ZipArchive;
     $res = $zip->open($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
          $zip->extractTo('../storage/unzipped/');
          $zip->close();

          // Get file, how? If I dont know the name, of the file inside the 
          // zip folder?


        } else {
            // Errors
        }
}
```

I definitely know how to open the file, IF I know the name.....but in this case, I wont know the name, so I need to somehow get it.   zip_entry_name()??

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I solved it before anyone could answer...so here it is for anyone that needs it.

```
$entry = $zip->getNameIndex(0);
```

Or if your file has multiple folders/files

```
$filenames=[];
for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
   $filenames[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
};
```

Full code

```
if($extension == 'ZIP' || $extension == 'zip'){
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 $res = $zip->open($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']);
    if ($res === TRUE) {
      $zip->extractTo('../storage/unzipped/');
      $filename = $zip->getNameIndex(0);
      // Open file or stream it or whatever you want
      // now that you have the name
      $zip->close();
    } else {
      // error
    } 
 }
```